# If $1+x^2=\sqrt{3}x$ then $\sum _{n=1}^{24}\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^2$ is equal to

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I tried this problem by different methods but i am not able to get the answer in easy way . First i found the roots of equation and then represented it in polar form of complex number . I got $\cos \left(30^{\circ}\right)\pm i\sin \left(30^{\circ}\right)$ . 
Then i tried to open whole square of question and the only thing i could sum up was that the terms of $x^2$ and $1/x^2$ must have cancelled and got the answer as $-48$ . I have seen one question like this in a book where equation was $x^2 + x + 1 =0$ and the roots of this equation are $\omega$ and $\omega ^2$ . Then they solved by putting values of $\omega$ in different sums but what if sum is large like upto $27$ terms ?

Is there a specific way to approach these kind of problems ?
Thanks for the help

Comment: You’ve got to put the TeX between dollar signs. And it’s strongly recommended that you state the problem not only in the title but in the body. Here, part of your title doesn’t even show.

Comment: Could you please edit it ? 
I honestly don't know how to write maths in mathjax form .

Comment: You had it right.  All I did was put dollar signs around the maths.

Comment: Hint : $\frac12 (x+1/x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) \implies (x^n+1/x^n)^2 = 4\cos^2\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\quad x=\cos 30^{\circ}+i\sin 30^{\circ}\quad$ from De Moivrè's formula follows
\begin{align}
x^n&=\cos (30^{\circ}n)+i\sin (30^{\circ}n)\\
\frac{1}{x^n}=x^{-n}&=\cos (30^{\circ}n)-i\sin (30^{\circ}n)\\
\end{align}

Hence,
$$x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}=2\cos(30^{\circ}n)\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, $\cos (x+360^{\circ})=\cos x$, so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{24}\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^{24}\left[2\cos(30^{\circ}n)\right]^2=4\sum_{n=1}^{24}\left[\cos(30^{\circ}n)\right]^2=2\cdot4 \sum_{n=1}^{12}\cos^2(30^{\circ}n)\tag{2}$$
As $\cos (x+180^{\circ})=-\cos x$ we get $\quad\cos^2 [30^{\circ}(k+6)]=\cos^2 (30^{\circ}k),\quad$ then ($2$) becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{24}\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)^2&=2\cdot4\cdot 2 \sum_{n=1}^{6}\cos^2(30^{\circ}n)\\
&=16\left[\cos^2 30^{\circ}+\cos^2 60^{\circ}+\cos^2 90^{\circ}+\cos^2(60^{\circ})+\cos^2(30^{\circ})+\cos^2(180^{\circ})\right]\\
&=16\left[2\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2+2\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+0+1\right]\\
&=16(3)\\
&=48
\end{align}
Here we have used the fact that $\;\;\;\cos (180^{\circ}-x)=-\cos x\;\;\;$ to get $\;\;\;\cos^2 (180^{\circ}-x)=\cos^2 x$. The same is true for $\;\;\; x=\cos 30^{\circ}-i\sin 30^{\circ}\;\;$ cause ($1$) is still true in such case.

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful , i could not figure out how to make it in terms of $2cos(x)$ .

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Should not the answer be -48 ?

Comment: Sorry my fault , the original question was ((x^n - 1/(x^n))^2 , still no problem .

Answer (score 5):

Each term is $x^{2n}+2+x^{-2n}=2+2\cos2n(30^\circ)$.  Set aside $\sum2=48$, and the cosines are $+1-1-2-1+1+2+1-1-2-1+1+2+1-1-2-1+1+2+1-1-2-1+1+2=0$
This works because $x^{2n}$ are complex numbers that form a regular hexagon centred at zero.  So do $x^{-2n}$.

Comment: Will answer be always summation of 2 in these type of questions or it will depend if summation is upto n terms where n is odd or even ?

Comment: The cosines only sum to zero if $n$ is a multiple of six, so there is a full hexagon.  The sum of 2 will always be $2n$.

Comment: Ok ,thanks for the help .